# Logitech MX518, keeps disconnecting and reconnecting periodically on my PC. (Win 7 64x)

Tags: windows, mouse

My Logitech MX518 mouse keeps disconnecting and reconnecting periodically. Here's a list of things I did

**THAT DID NOT WORK**
 - Tried using different USB ports. Same issue.
 - Used the same mouse on my girlfriends computer and it works fine. Leads me to believe not hardware    issue.
 - Changing power settings of Root Hubs in Device Manager.
 - Uninstall Root Hubs, HID compliant mouse, and Logitech Mouse Drivers, reboot and re-installed them.

I don't know what else to do. My gut tells me it's really not a hardware issue though. The problem would reproduce itself on other systems if the mouse had a hardware issue, no?

Comment: What means periodically? Any 2 seconds? 1-10 times an hour? Any change, while not used?
If I had USB problems on Windows, I always went to device manager and removed any USB device. After rebooting, windows re-initializes the drivers and often it worked then.

Comment: Are any other devices having any issues on usb? Try a different mouse and see if the issue is reproduced.

Comment: Try to move and crumple mouse's cable, at both ends of the cable (near USB and mouse). Lot of people has this problem and fixing it is easy (lot of YT tutorials).